# ¿problema de autentificar usuarios con devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

estoy empezando con ruby on rails estoy utilizando la gema devise cuando quiero ingresar un correo con una password me sale este error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a que se debe??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Desinstala bcrypt**

```
gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby
gem uninstall bcrypt
gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

Luego agrega en tu *Gemfile*:

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'
```

Y, por último, ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: ¿y que es lo que hace ese archivo específicamente?

Comment: @DanteAligeri La gema _Bcrypt_ se utiliza para mantener seguras las contraseñas de los usuarios (puedes ver la documentación en inglés [aquí](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/)) y es requerida por _Devise_. Al parecer esta gema (_Bcrypt_) tiene problemas específicamente con instalaciones windows ([aquí](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142) puedes ver el registro del problema en inglés), y lo único que estás haciendo es desinstalara y luego instalarla.

Comment: gracias ya lo pude solucionar

Comment: @DanteAligeri Excelente! Si la respuesta te sirvió para solucionar el problema por favor márcala como aceptada (dando clic en la paloma a la izquierda); si tu solución fue otra por favor agrégala como respuesta para que alguien más que se encuentre con este problema pueda aprovechar de tu solución. Suerte!